# <lightning:card> not working properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I tried to use `lightning:card` in my Lightning Component which is not working properly

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:card>
        <aura:set attribute="title">
            Hello!
        </aura:set>
        <aura:set attribute="footer">
            <lightning:badge label="footer"/>
        </aura:set>
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="New"/>
        </aura:set>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            Card Body (custom component)
        </p>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue

Comment: can you explain the behavior of "not working properly", maybe add a screenshot, so we can better understand and help

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the component in inside a lightning page using app Builder or inside a lightning application using

```
<aura:application extends='force:slds'> tags.
```

Comment: Actually, the lightning:card took the full width of the window, so I am not able to identify its presence inside the lightning component. I tried it by reducing its width, now I can see it clearly. thanks for all replies